# Using Rank() information to remove scores by row

Tags: r

I am trying to manually examine outliers within each row of a dataframe. To do this I would like to remove the highest score in a row (ignoring missing values), calculate the upper bound of scores (Mean of remaining scores plus the standard deviation multiplied by 2.5). Then compare the removed highest score to the upper bound. If the score is lower then I want to return the score to the dataframe.

```
Score 1     Score 2    Score 3   Score 4    Score 5    Score 6    
2834.0000  3390.0000  932.4050  1088.4851  1047.3301  1059.3850 
1409.2500     NA         NA     1256.8899   868.0601  1480.8149
```

Unfortunately, there is not a consistent level that the scores fall above or a column that the scores are contained. For example, the highest score in row 1 is 3390 in column 2, while the highest score in row 2 is 1480.8149 in column 6.

The "closest" I have got is to apply rank() to identify the largest score in each row. I have also applied scale() to calculate z-scores for each score per row (however, it is based on a potentially inflated mean). But now I do not know how to use that information to remove scores on a separate dataframe.

I am new to R so please forgive me if there is a simple command for this problem.

Comment: Nice first question! Clear, reproducible,...  Welcome to the site :)

Comment: Will there be ties in the scores?

Comment: Thanks! Glad to be here and learn more advanced techniques.

Comment: @bouncyball I doubt there will be ties because it is all reaction time data. However, if there are, I think I would like them both to be placed back in the data set. Because of a low number of scores 2/6 scores could be heavily influencing the mean suggesting they may not be outliers in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do what you want:

```
t(apply(dat, 1, function(r){
    r_new <- r #new vector
    find_max <- which(r_new == max(r_new, na.rm = TRUE)) #find max value
    r_new[find_max] <- NA #replace with NA
    #calculate upper
    upper <- mean(r_new, na.rm = TRUE) + (2.5) * sd(r_new, na.rm = TRUE)
    # replace if necessary
    if(all(upper > r[find_max])){ # use all in case of ties
        r_new[find_max] <- r[find_max]
    }
    r_new #return new vector        
}))

      Score1 Score2  Score3   Score4    Score5   Score6
[1,] 2834.00   3390 932.405 1088.485 1047.3301 1059.385
[2,] 1409.25     NA      NA 1256.890  868.0601 1480.815
```

We use `apply` to iterate over the rows of your data. Then, we look at the largest value in each row, set it to `NA`, calculate your upper limit, check to see if the upper limit is larger than the largest value.

Comment: You could do `find_max <- which.max(r_new)`, which will be equivalent (unless there is a tie for the max, in which case `which.max` will only return the first max).

Comment: Right, I think leaving it as is would be safer in the case of ties, but I will need to update the logic in the `if` statement.

Comment: Depends on what OP wants with ties... removing one max at a time might be just fine.

Comment: Thank you! This works well and I am glad it was not something too simple that was alluding me. I did not want to waste anyone's time.

Quick tip for any future viewers: you will get an error if there are any rows that contain entirely missing data. Make sure you clean up the data set before running the code above.